# Setting up a master page for scenes

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, interface-builder

*Note: I am not talking about Master-Detail SplitViews!*

There is a question similar to this ([Master page concept in Iphone development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970203/master-page-concept-in-iphone-development)), but the question only refers to standard features, not the layout itself. Also, the answers only show how to avoid duplicate code, but you still have to link the IBActions on every scene. Maybe we can extend the linked question and discover some better solutions :-)

So, I'd like to define a master page for all the scenes/view controllers in my app. That's a common task for example in web development (i.e. [ASP.NET Masterpages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX)).

The master page would both include the actual layout (background color, where the title goes, where the content goes etc.) and standard features present in all scenes (open menu, go back, open help page, etc.)

Using Interface Builder (with or without Storyboard), what would be the best way to accomplish that?

Here are my ideas:

**Option 1: Subclass UIViewController for standard features, copypaste the common layout in every scene/viewcontroller.**

Advantages: Fairly easy to use, just copypaste all controls, set parent class in IB and connect the standard feature buttons.

Disadvantages: Tedious if you have loads of scenes, you can easily forget to connect standard features. If for any reason the master layout changes, you're screwed.

**Option 2: Subclass UIViewController, add layout programmatically somewhere in `viewDidLoad`, where you also setup the event targets**

Advantages: Both the layout and the features are handled at a single place and are easily changeable.

Disadvantages: You need to setup the layout programmatically, which is inconsistent if you use IB everywhere else. You don't see the master layout in IB, so you must "imagine" it to be there while configuring the rest of the scene in IB. 
Without Storyboard, you could use XIBs to only design the content view, but then you never have the "whole picture" in IB. Also, this doesn't work with Storyboards.

Both options don't seem very elegant to me. What's your approach to do this (this has got to be a common issue!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this.  Two of my favorite ways follow.

In both of them, you start out with the (using your term) MasterVC.  Do all the layout and design for the common elements.  Then for the contentView, either:

1. Put in a separate view, and add childViewControllers programmatically; or
2. Put in a containerView that holds a UICollectionView.  Create a cell in the collectionView that takes up the entire collectionView.  Create a custom cell class with one outlet (pageView, in my example), and load the ViewControllers from storyboard in one of two ways.  Either set the identifiers of your VCs to numbers that represent where they will appear in the collectionView, or create an array of VC names.  Then whenever the user navigates to a certain VC, you tell the collectionVC to scroll to that index.

The implementation in cellForItemAtIndexPath would look something like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AMMasterCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath ];

    for (UIView *view in cell.pageView.subviews)
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    NSString *viewID = self.arrayOfViewControllerNames[indexPath.item];

    AMMasterViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewID];
    AMMasterView *pageView = (AMMasterView *)viewController.view;
    [cell.pageView addSubview:pageView];

    [self addChildViewController:viewController];                 
    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    return cell;
}
```

I've done this a bunch of times, and it works beautifully.

Comment: Your idea with UICollectionView is clever. In iOS5/6 however, there are UIContainerViews that I think do exactly what I want. UICollectionView brought me there, so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your standard layout includes the creation controls that are linked to your code via IBOutlets you only have two ways of adding them on the storyboard or programmatically. Logic so far.

Now this is how I would think about it. If all of your views have the same controls (unlikely)  then you can build one view in storyboard and spawn it. In the more logical case that they share a series of controls and you want to standardise those you have three choices.

1. You build your standard design in storyboard and add the controls needed in each view programmatically
2. You build the standard design programmatically and add the other controls in storyboard
3. Do everything programmatically

I would most likely chose option 2 and organise it this way:

1. Create a function `setupView` to setup the standard design
2. In the view did load of each view using the design I would call `[whereEverYouPutThis  setupView];`

Using this option you can make the change to your master in one place very quickly and you can use storyboard to make the view specific stuff.